# multiple react native animations with reanimated base on a state?

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-reanimated

I am new to react native animations and I am specifically using react native reanimated, this is my code old code which is used in text input, I am changing the fontsize and translate Y of a label:

```
  const labelSize = new Animated.Value(14);
  const translateY = new Animated.Value(0);
  const onFocus = () => {
     setHasFocused(true);
     Animated.timing(labelSize, {
       toValue: 11,
       duration: 250,
       easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease),
     }).start();
     Animated.timing(top, {
       toValue: -14,
       duration: 250,
       easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease),
     }).start();
  };
  const onBlur = () => { 
     setHasFocused(false);
     Animated.timing(labelSize, {
       toValue: 14,
       duration: 250,
       easing: Easing.out(Easing.ease),
     }).start();
     Animated.timing(top, {
       toValue: 0,
       duration: 250,
       easing: Easing.in(Easing.ease),
     }).start();
  };
```

however it doesn't seem to feel right, I've researched and resulted to this, I believe I have to use clock and timing with this, which I find hard and can't make to work, what I want to do is something like this:

```
const clock = new Clock();
useCode(
  () => [
    set(isPlaying, hasFocused ? 1 : 0),
    set(translateY, hasFocused ? 1 : 0),
  ],
  [hasFocused]
);
```

now I believe with timing I have to use clock with it:

```
  const state = {
    finished: new Animated.Value(0),
    position: new Animated.Value(0),
    frameTime: new Animated.Value(0),
    time: new Animated.Value(0),
  };
  const config = {
    toValue: new Animated.Value(1),
    duration: 3000,
    easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease),
  };
  timing(clock, state, config)
```

what I simply want to do is update animation values based if the input is focused and not, help?